# Is there a way that a scrolling div can trigger another div to scroll using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using two div elements

When a user scrolls div #element-A I would like #element-A to automatically scroll in the same position as #element-b

My Current code is below:

```js
var currentPlan = $('#current-A'),
  optionsPlan = $('#current-B'),
  combinedScroll = optionsPlan.scrollTop();

optionsPlan.scroll(function() {

  currentPlan.scroll();
});
```

```css
#element-A,
#element-B {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  float: left;
  overflow: auto;
}

#element-A {
  background: orange;
}

#element-B {
  background: yellow;
}

.content {
  padding-bottom: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="element-A">
  <div class="content">
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <h1 id="header-one-target" Header One</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="element-B">
  <div class="content">
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
    <h1 id="animate-hd-b">Header Two</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

I know that I'm missing something simple in my jQuery but I can't seem to find the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
            
  let target = $("#current-B")[0];
  $("#current-A").scroll(function() {
    target.scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
  });
```

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.scroll-box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
<div class="scroll-box" id="current-A"> 
  <p>item</p>
  <p>item</p>
  <p>item</p>
  <p>item</p>
  <p>item</p>
  <p>item</p>
  <p>item</p>
  <p>item</p>
  <p>item</p>
  <p>item</p>
  <p>item</p>
  <p>item</p>
</div>

<div class="scroll-box" id="current-B"> 
  <p>item item item item item item item</p>
  <p>item</p>
  <p>item</p>
  <p>item</p>
  <p>item</p>
  <p>item</p>
  <p>item</p>
  <p>item</p>
  <p>item</p>
  <p>item</p>
  <p>item</p>
  <p>item</p>
</div>
<section>
```

Comment: This breaks if you make it two-directional (so scrolling the other left div also scrolls the right div). This wasn't stated as a requirement in the question, but I assume it's what the OP wants. It also hasn't been stated what's supposed to happen if the contents are of different length (either scrolling by exact pixel amount, like in your provided code, or by percentage of scroll position to total height)

Comment: Why don't we add scrollLeft too then?

Comment: @Connum As for the amount scrolled based on content length, I'm all ears :)

Comment: No, I didn't mean two-directional in the sense of x/y or left/right, but syncing both divs to each other :)

Comment: @Connum  Yes I would like to sync both divs together vertically

Comment: @StefanBob I only need to scoll vertically Y

Comment: @Jimmy Okay take my hand. Edited

Comment: @StefanBob Works for me

Answer (score 0):

**Jquery**

```
$('#element-A').on('scroll', function () {
    $('#element-B').scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
});
```

**CSS** (if you don't want the scrollbar in the synchronized div)

```
#element-B{
    overflow : hidden;
}
```

### **Code Snippet**

```js
$('#element-A').on('scroll', function () {
    $('#element-B').scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
});
```

```css
#element-B{
   overflow : hidden;
   display: inline-block;
   height: 100px;
   position: absolute;
   right:50px;
}

#element-A{
   display: inline-block;
   height: 100px;
   overflow : scroll;
   width:155px;
}
```

```html
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <div id="element-A">
          <div class="content">
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p> 
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
            <h1 id="header-one-target"Header One</h1>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="element-B">
          <div class="content">
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p> 
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
            <h1 id="animate-hd-b">Header Two</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
```